# C++ How to alternate between getline and integers with fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

The file im dealing with for input looks like:

Student Name

GPA

Student Name

GPA

etc..

Ive tried using getline followed by fin (my file input command) but i keep getting errors.

I cannot use vectors as i must use getline. I am allowed using fin.ignore() among other but not sure what to do.

```
while (!fin.eof()) {
    getline(fin, studentNames[i]);
    fin >> studentGPA[i];
    cout << studentNames[i] << endl;
    cout << studentGPA[i] << endl;
    ++i;
    cout << numberOfStudents << endl;
    ++numberOfStudents;
}
```

Comment: You should use regex or something to validate the file line, then if it matches a certain pattern, (i.e. is a float) use `std::atoi` or something. Also seems like a pretty stupid and inefficient way to store data in a file.

Comment: What errors do you get ???

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong?s=1|135.7997)

Comment: This is what i changed the code to but i want it to continue with ther other names and GPA of the other students.                                 
   while (getline(fin, studentNames[i])) {
        cout << studentNames[i] << endl;
        fin >> studentGPA[i];
        fin.ignore(SIZE_MAX, '/n');
        cout << studentGPA[i] << endl;
        ++i;
        cout << numberOfStudents << endl << endl;
        ++numberOfStudents;
    }

Comment: Read a line; store it as text; read a line; convert it to a number and store it; repeat until done.